# Is there a way to detect if a window is making noise?

Tags: node.js, audio, window, detect

I’m trying to make a simple node.js project which would log when a window (not browser window) made any auditable noise.

According to other questions it seems not possible in browser, but I’m curious if that other windows would work.

Thanks!